# Variable names in vscode debugger are reduced to one letter instead of full variable names

Tags: visual-studio-code

I created a configuration in `launch.json`.
When I run using this configuration the variable names in my code are not used as variable names in the vscode debugging console.

Instead all variable names are reduced to one letter. For example a variable defined as `const name` in the code will  show as the letter `e` in the vscode debugging console.

This also causes that I am unable to hover variables in the code to look for their value.

**How come the variable names are reduced to one letter in the vscode debugging console?**

Here is the launch config I use. Here it's used to run serverless functions locally. Though I suspect the issue is not related to that.
If necessary I can provide more info.

```
{
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Run one Serverless function",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/sls",
      "args": [
        "invoke",
        "local",
        "--function",
        "nameOfTheFunction",
        "--path",
        "./myEvent.json"
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "env": { "AWS_PROFILE": "myProfile", "SLS_DEBUG": "*" }
    }
```

Comment: Does your build have a minifying step? Maybe so, and maybe source maps are not set up correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by build? The code itself is written in JavaScript so it's not really build. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @DavidP.Caldwell, are you suspecting it has something to do with webpack?

Comment: Nice, that's it. I was running webpack with `mode: 'production'`. This caused the above behavior. For full variable names use: `mode: 'development'`

Comment: Excellent! Glad you got it figured out.